# Page has made too many redirects

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, apache2

Ok, So I have purchased a domain www.webuilder.co.uk and so in my ubuntu server I have changed .htaccess file with rewrite rule to show www.webuilder.co.uk instead of my IP however it now says that website (my IP) has made too many redirects. How can that be fixed, I am using apache2 + webmin + laravel with ubuntu server 16.04 as my virtual host. Also when I enter www.webuilder.co.uk and then click refresh it changes address to my ip and if refreshed again it changes it back to www.webuilder.com.

In my network interfaces I have:

```
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static

address 192.168.1.105
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

In apache.conf:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
ServerName "http://www.webuilder.co.uk"
```

So now if you type : webuilder.co.uk I get a website with address 95.147.111.102

if I type 95.147.111.102/ I get website with 95.147.111.102/

if I type my ip 192.168.1.105 I get same website with address 192.168.1.105

Comment: What dose your virtual hosts for the domain look like in Apache config. you shouldn't need to make a rewrite rule to make you're domain show up instead of you're ip.

Comment: just checked you A records and they are not correct. don't use you're local ip address use you public IP address.

Comment: so what should I do to solve it? I have a router and I don't know how to check and set public ip address @Neil

Comment: Dose your Ubuntu machine hosted out side of your NAT.

Comment: You need to set A record for www.webuilder.co.uk with public IP, then only you can access from externally. What is that IP 95.147.111.102.

Comment: my ubuntu machine is bridged, website works outside using different network etc. It is the ip that was set by my router when i set port forwarding. I had to do that to make it work outside of my network. Funny thing is it website work on both ip addresses

Comment: @Przemek type `my ip` in google. then change you're A record from `95.147.111.102` with what ever ip address google says you have. you're public ip address is not determined by you're router.

Comment: @Przemek take out the `http` in `ServerName` just have `www.webuilder.co.uk`